# Break command doesn't stop loop

Tags: python

The Break Command Doesnt work and when i try to run it, it gets stuck like it cant compile because its stuck in a loop

My code isn't running at all, I have reviewed my code but it doesn't seem to work. Everything is fine for me.

```
import random
# print("Winning Rules of the Rock paper scissor game as follows: \n"
#       + "Rock vs paper->paper wins \n"
#       + "Rock vs scissor->Rock wins \n"
#       + "paper vs scissor->scissor wins \n")
while True: 
 def main():
    print("Enter choice \n 1. Rock \n 2. paper \n 3. scissor \n")
    try : 
        choice_name = (input("User turn: "))
        if choice_name == 1:
            choice_name = 'Rock'
        if choice_name == 2:
            choice_name = 'paper'
        if choice_name == 3:
            choice_name = 'scissor'
        else: 
            choice_name = None
            input("Atleast Enter a Valid Number like BRUHHHHHHHHH: ")
    except ValueError: 
        print ("Try again")     
        main()
    print("user choice is: " + choice_name)
    print("\nNow its computer turn.......")

    Computer_Choice = random.randint(1, 3)

    while Computer_Choice == choice_name:
        Computer_Choice = random.randint(1, 3)

    if Computer_Choice == 1:
        Computer_Choice_name = 'Rock'
    elif Computer_Choice == 2:
        Computer_Choice_name = 'paper'
    else:
        Computer_Choice_name = 'scissor'

    print("Computer choice is: " + Computer_Choice_name)

    print(choice_name + " V/s " + Computer_Choice_name)

    if((choice_name == 1 and Computer_Choice == 2) or
       (choice_name == 2 and Computer_Choice == 1)):
        print("paper wins => ", end="")
        result = "paper"

    elif((choice_name == 1 and Computer_Choice == 3) or
         (choice_name == 3 and Computer_Choice == 1)):
        print("Rock wins =>", end="")
        result = "Rock"
    else:
        print("scissor wins =>", end="")
        result = "scissor"

    if result == choice_name:
        print("<== User wins ==>")
    else:
        print("<== Computer wins ==>")

    print("Do you want to play again? (Y/N)")
    ans = input()

    if ans == 'n' or ans == 'N': 
     break
print("\nThanks for playing")
```

Comment: All your code does is to define a function called `main` over and over in a `while True` loop without ever calling that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a function inside of a `while` loop. Currently the loop always evaluates to `False`.

What you want is:

```py
def main():
    while True:
        # ...
```

Then you need to actually call `main`. At the end of the file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```